# How to localize ActiveModel::Error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-i18n

When I validate a model I get the following error

```
<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ffecf1c9460 
@base=#<Post id: nil, created_at: nil, label_id: nil, user_id: 3>,
@messages={:label=>["can't be blank"]},
@details={:label=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

How can I customize the error message?

From my understanding, the following should work

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        post:
          attributes:
            label:
              blank: do not like it
```

However, I still get the default error message.

Answer (score 5):

It's ActiveModel, not ActiveRecord you want to localize:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      models:
        post:
          attributes:
            base:
              label:
                blank: do not like it
```

From [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models):

> If you are using a class which includes ActiveModel and does not
>   inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, replace `activerecord` with `activemodel`.

Comment: @Зелёный it's [ActiveModel](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html) OP asks about, not ActiveRecord :)

Comment: My class inherits from `ApplicationRecord` so from `ActiveRecord::Base`.
Anyway, I have tried to localize ActiveModel + restarted the server (just in case)  but I Still getting the default message.

Comment: @macsig you've missed `base` key :) Edited the answer

Comment: The validation is automatically added by Rails5 `belongs_to` and it turned out that the correct key I should define is `required` regardless the `details` of  ActiveModel::Errors